# How to get rid of the line break in HTML

Tags: html, css, whitespace, space

How do I make my text appear all on the same line? I'm making a menu in HTML and I have the following source

```
<h2> Blue Moon 20oz </h2>....<b> $5.00 </b>
```

In my mind the h2 setting are obviously being applied to "Blue Moon" then there are regular dots without any style and then on the same line you have the $5.00 in bold. When I run this though It looks like this:

> **Blue Moon**
>
> ...$5.00

instead of what i would like to see, which is:

> **Blue Moon**....$5.00

Ive tried using the `<span>`,`<pre>` and `<br />` tags and none of them seem to keep them from auto-breaking to another line(although I could be placing the tags in the wrong places).

Sorry, I know I'm probably doing a poor job explaining this but hopefully I was able to get my point across. Thanks!

Comment: h2, h1, all Hx tags are block tags. They will have that effect. If you want them to be inline you will have to touch some css. Btw, your question is not asked properly and it was quite hard to understand.

Comment: Yeah my fault. This is literally my first post on here ever. I didnt realize that if I typed a tag out that it would actually function. So when I typed things like "pre" or "span" they didnt display

Comment: You need to take a little while to understand the basics of the box model and how different display models can be applied to each rectangular element https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is pretty simple.
 by default rendered this way. You need to set `display: inline-block` to it in css or try to use inline tags, like span.

Go deeper in CSS and you'll understand all the reasons :)

Comment: Thanks that worked very well! I figured it was doing it by default but couldnt quite figure out a workaround. You're the bomb!

Answer (score 0):

I am made some small piece of code (if i understand your problem properly).H2 is by default act as display block. You just need to give inline-block if you want to show this in one line. 
Have a look on this: `https://jsfiddle.net/p64ymc18/`

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h2>Blue Moon</h2>...$5.00
</div>
```

CSS:
    h2{display:inline-block;}